# Botão de compartilhamento para o linkedin

Tags: jquery, html5, css3

Como eu posso fazer um botão para compartilhamento para o linkedin? Eu fiz do facebook, google, twitter e whatsapp mas do linkedin não estou conseguindo. Por exemplo olhem esse do facebook:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var win = null;
    function novaJanela(pagina, nome, w, h, scroll) {
        LeftPosition = (screen.width) ? (screen.width - w) / 2 : 0;
        TopPosition = (screen.height) ? (screen.height - h) / 2 : 0;
        settings = 'height=' + h + ',width=' + w + ',top=' + TopPosition + ',left=' + LeftPosition + ',scrollbars=' + scroll + ',resizable'
        win = window.open(pagina, nome, settings);
    }
</script>

<div class="social-ctn fb">
     <a href="#" onclick="NovaJanela('http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://www.cissamagazine.com.br/blog/xperia-c5-ultra-m5-reis-da-fotografia', '', '550', '470', 'yes');return false">
         <div class="icon"></div>
         <span class="text facebook">Facebook</span>                           
     </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="social-ctn linkedin-new">
     <a href="#" onclick="novaJanela('http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&amp;url=http://local.cissamagazine.com.br/mais-vendidos&amp;title=Os 20 Smartphones mais vendidos&amp;summary=Os 20 Smartphones mais vendidos', '', '550', '510', 'yes'); return false">
         <span class="icon"></span>
         <span class="text linkedin">Linkedin</span>
     </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você deve implementar a API deles, de uma olhada em:

https://developer.linkedin.com/

Escolha a linguagem que você deseja utilizar.

Comment: Mas nesse caso eu gostaria de fazer como fiz no exemplo acima pois usando API deles eu sou obrigado a fazer uma requisição cada vez que eu carrego a página